# SQL Query to get the count of Json Array

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2019

I have the below Json object. How do I get the count of Object Array.

```
{
  "Model": [
    {
  "ModelName": "Test Model",    
  "Object": [
     {
       "ID": 1,
       "Name": "ABC"           

     },
     {
       "ID": 11,
       "Name": "ABCD"          
    },         
 ]  
 }]}
```

I tried the below query but seems JSON_Length was not available.

```
SELECT ModelName,
       JSON_LENGTH(JsonData, '$.Model[0].Object')
    FROM TabA
```

The expected output should be

```
 ModelName      COUNT
 Test Model      2
```

Comment: The JSON you've provided isn't valid; unless you have valid JSON, you won't be able to use any of the JSON functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have valid JSON (at the moment you have a trailing comma (`,`_ after one of your closing braces (`}`)), then you could use `OPENJSON` and `COUNT`:

```
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{
  "Model": [
    {
  "ModelName": "Test Model",    
  "Object": [
     {
       "ID": 1,
       "Name": "ABC"           

     },
     {
       "ID": 11,
       "Name": "ABCD"          
    }         
 ]  
 }]}';

SELECT M.ModelName,
       COUNT(O.[key]) AS [Count]
FROM (VALUES(@JSON))V(J)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.J)
                 WITH(ModelName varchar(20) '$.Model[0].ModelName',
                      [Object] nvarchar(MAX) '$.Model[0].Object' AS JSON) M
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(M.[Object]) O
GROUP BY M.ModelName;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of @Thom A's answer `use OPENJSON and COUNT:`, by eliminating the `CROSS APPLY`s:

```
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{
  "Model": [
    {
  "ModelName": "Test Model",    
  "Object": [
     {
       "ID": 1,
       "Name": "ABC"           

     },
     {
       "ID": 11,
       "Name": "ABCD"          
    }         
 ]  
 }]}';

select [ModelName] = JSON_value(@JSON, N'$.Model[0].ModelName')
     , [COUNT]     = count(*) 
  from openJSON(@JSON, N'$.Model[0].Object');
```

result:

| ModelName | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| Test Model | 2 |